# web.Whatsapp headlessly using phantomjs

Tags: browser, phantomjs, whatsapp

Using Phantomjs with to start web session on web.whatsapp.com, using chrome's user-agent as whatsapp not support phantomjs as user-agent

Code as Follows :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36';
    page.viewportSize = {
      width: 1200,
      height: 800
    };
    page.open('https://web.whatsapp.com/', function() {
      page.render('home.png');
      phantom.exit();
    });
```

But the output is **blank white screen with dot on center**

[script output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bqvx.png)

any bug in my code or is there any compatible issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phantomjs is not waiting to load page completely, you can see elastic loading page icon.

Try this code with sleep.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

user_agent = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
)

dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = user_agent

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, executable_path=r'/bin/phantomjs')


driver.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')
timeout = 30
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.Class, 'qrcode'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
```

Note : whatsapp need **cryptoSha256 and cryptoAesCbc** supported browser for proper crypt management, Phantom js is not supporting cryptoSha256 and cryptoAesCbc.

Comment: You're right, there is any other way to implement WhatsApp on phantomjs ?

Comment: @AnantaSharma, are you able to access whatsapp QR code using phantomjs ?

Comment: create a img file of actual QR, save it, open it and scan it with your celphone